# Count deviations in two ranges of cells

Tags: mac

Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
Correct answers: A C A B D B ...

Student:         Answers:            Score:
--------         --------            ------
Charlie A.       A D A B D C ...     4/6
George B.        A C A B D D ...     5/6
```

How do you count the right answers by comparing the answers from each student with the answers in the first row? I want to be able to compute the score of the tests by entering in the answers.

Comment: Are the answers in their own cells?  How many answers are there?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a shell script that just prints the number of same characters without doing any formatting:

```
#!/bin/bash

solutions="ACABDB"
input="Charlie A.,ADABDC
George B.,ACABDD"
IFS=$'\n'
for line in $input; do
  name=${line%,*}
  answers=${line#*,}
  correct=0
  for i in $(seq ${#solutions}); do
    [ ${answers:$i:1} == ${solutions:$i:1} ] && ((correct++))
  done
  echo "$line,$correct"
done
```

And a Ruby version that formats the results as a monospace table:

```
solutions = "ACABDB"
"Charlie A.,ADABDC
George B.,ACABDD".split("\n").each { |line|
  name, answer = line.split(",")
  correct = 0
  (0...solutions.length).each { |i|
    correct += 1 if answer[i] == solutions[i]
  }
  puts "#{"%-17s" % name}#{"%-20s" % answer.split("").join(" ")}#{correct}/#{solutions.length}"
}
```

You can save the scripts with TextEdit (in plain text mode) and then run them from Terminal with something like `bash ~/Desktop/script.sh` or `ruby ~/Desktop/script.rb`.